# latex l3sys get exit code of script

Tags: latex3, shell-escape

I am using l3sys of the latex3 interfaces, i need to get the exit code of a script after running it. I am running `\sys_get_shell:nnN`, i tried giving it `echo $?` and `echo \$`, but the shell for some reason interprets `$?` as the literal characters not the exit code of the last command, thus `echo $?` fails because it is missing one $ for a math environment, and `echo \$?` fails with `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].` for some reason, that i do not know.

Is there a way to make this work, or is there an interface to the exit code that i missed, or can i make a command fail if the script fails in some other way?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: tried both on a windows machine, and an arch running in virtualbox on said windows.

Comment: On second thought im starting to doubt that i did it on linux might just have thought of doing it, will try again when i have time. This might be the error.

Comment: Tried on linux, i actually get a result with `$?` now, but it is always zero no matter the previous command.